# Angular variable not binding to view but updated in logs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is most annoying problem I have ever had.

**My html snippet**:

```
    <!--test_management.html-->
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as tcl">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Populated Tests</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane2" ng-click="loadOnAdditionalData()" data-toggle="tab">Additional Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane6" ng-click="loadJenkinsData()" data-toggle="tab">Jenkins Jobs</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <br />
    <button type="button" ng-click="runTests()" class="btn btn-primary active">Run Tests</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="toggleRunModal()" class="btn btn-primary active">Check Run Status</button>
    <br />
    <br />
      <li class="active"><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Selected Tests</a></li>
      <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">NextGen Tests</a></li>
      <li><a href="#pane5" data-toggle="tab">Default Tests</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Test Name</th>
    <th>Set CPD Flag</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in populated_tests_data" class="info">
    <th>[[test]]</th>
    <th><md-switch class="md-primary" md-no-ink aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model='set' ng-change="addTestToRunlist(test)">
    </md-switch></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
<div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Test Name</th>
  <th>Set CPD Flag</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="test in nextgen_list[current_pr]" class="info">
  <th>[[test]]</th>
  <th><md-switch class="md-primary" md-no-ink aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model='set' ng-change="addTestToRunlist(test)">
  </md-switch></th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="pane5" class="tab-pane">
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Test Name</th>
  <th>Set CPD Flag</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
    <br />
    <md-switch class="md-primary" ng-model="granularityLevel" aria-label="Switch 2" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-change="loadOnAdditionalData(page_no_tests)"><label>Show test level granularity</label></md-switch>
  <br />
      <md-autocomplete flex md-selected-item="selectedTest" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-floating-label="Search Test Feature Name">
    <md-item-template>
      <span md-highlight-text="searchText">[[item.display]]</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
      No matches found.
    </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
  <center>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>
   <button ng-click="previousPageTests()" class="btn btn-default">&nbsp;&laquo;&nbsp;</button>
   </th>
   <th>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;[[page_no_tests]] / [[test_feature_name_pages]]&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </th>
   <th>
     <button ng-click="nextPageTests()" class="btn btn-default">&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;</button>
   </th>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </center>
  <!--<md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="progress_on" md-diameter="50"></md-progress-circular>-->
    <treecontrol class="tree-classic"
   tree-model="testDataWithBranch"
   options="treeOptions"
   on-selection="updateTestData(node)"
   selected-node="node1"
   >
   [[node.name]]
  </treecontrol>
  <br /><br />
  <center>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>
   <button ng-click="previousPageTests()" class="btn btn-default">&nbsp;&laquo;&nbsp;</button>
   </th>
   <th>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;[[page_no_tests]] / [[test_feature_name_pages]]&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </th>
   <th>
     <button ng-click="nextPageTests()" class="btn btn-default">&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;</button>
   </th>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </center>
</div>
<div id="pane6" class="tab-pane">
  [[tcl.jenkins_jobs_data]]
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**app.js (Inside TestCtrl controller.)**

```
$scope.loadJenkinsData = function(){
  $scope.jenkins_jobs_data = [];
  $http.get("/jenkins_jobs_by_product/ESX").then(
    function(response){
  $scope.jenkins_jobs_data = response.data;
  console.log($scope.jenkins_jobs_data);
} );
};
```

Now when the tab is opened and loadJenkinsData is executed, in my logs I can see that the data is printed accurately, suggesting that $scope.jenkins_jobs_data has been successfully updated.

But on the html page it prints an empty array where it is supposed to get the value with which jenkins_jobs_data.

I have written similar code before and it has worked. Why is this different? Any suggetions on debugging this issue or resolving it would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.: I have tried using $scope.$apply() at the end of loadJenkinsData(), and it hasn't helped.

Comment: This snippet looks fine, the evil must be in other parts of the code. I suspect some scope inheritance here. Could you post more of the html to see if there is a child scope defined somewhere?

Comment: Ok I am gonna give u large html snippet here.

Comment: Larger html snippet added.

Comment: Hey Tamas, great clue on scope inheritance. It eventually truned out to be the issue. Thanks, Rijo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunker with a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FTwXSe1CS366hO6piZiJ?p=preview). I created a dummy ESX file that contains a string "some data in ESX".

Probably a scope issue, with $scope being different in the function(response) than in the loadJenkinsData. Try

```
$scope.loadJenkinsData = function(){
  var myscope = $scope;
  myscope.jenkins_jobs_data = [];
  $http.get("/jenkins_jobs_by_product/ESX").then(
    function(response){
  myscope.jenkins_jobs_data = response.data;
  console.log(myscope.jenkins_jobs_data);
} );
};
```

To avoid those issues, I put "this" in a variable like "vm":

```
var vm = this;
vm.loadJenkinsData = function(){
  vm.jenkins_jobs_data = [];
  $http.get("/jenkins_jobs_by_product/ESX").then(
    function(response){
  vm.jenkins_jobs_data = response.data;
  console.log(vm.jenkins_jobs_data);
} );
};
```

Let us know.

I also changed the HTML to use the Controller as construct:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <p>Hello {{vm.name}}!</p>
  <li><a href="#pane6" ng-click="vm.loadJenkinsData()" data-toggle="tab">Jenkins Jobs</a></li>
  <div id="pane6" class="tab-pane">
    {{vm.jenkins_jobs_data}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey Gregori, thanks for the quick response. I tried both the approached above. In the first case, the current buggy behavior continued to exists, where the updated value is reflected properly when logging into the console, but failed to update the value in the view. In the second case however, neither the console log nor the view had the updated value.

Comment: @RijoSimon I added a plunker as an example using your code and the second version vm=this. I created a dummy ESX file.

Comment: @RijoSimon The plunker is at the top of my answer and here https://plnkr.co/edit/FTwXSe1CS366hO6piZiJ?p=preview

Comment: If you copy the original code to plunker which uses $scope that works too.

Comment: Yea none of this is helping me. This is something completely different. And as I said, I have similar code for my other tabs, and they are all working fine.

Comment: @RijoSimon Sorry about that. I updated the plunker with your larger HTML snippet and my test data appears at the end of the page when one presses the Jenking jobs link: https://plnkr.co/edit/FTwXSe1CS366hO6piZiJ?p=preview I had to change one ng-click to <a href="#pane6" ng-click="tcl.loadJenkinsData()" and how the data is printed at the end of the page to   <div id="pane6" class="tab-pane">
        {{ tcl.jenkins_jobs_data}}
      </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try Gregori's second snippet and modify your view

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl">
...
...
 <li><a href="#pane6" ng-click="ctrl.loadJenkinsData()" data-toggle="tab">Jenkins      Jobs</a></li>
 ...
 ...
<div id="pane6" class="tab-pane">
  {{ctrl.jenkins_jobs_data}}
</div>
...
```

try it :)

Comment: Sorry man, I forgot to insert ctrl. before loadJenkisData()
Avoid use of $scope, use 'this' property attached to a variable like 'vm' in Gregori's snippet